# PyPy large memory usage compared to CPython

Tags: python, io, cpython, pypy

I used python to solve SPOJ's large input test [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/INTEST/) and met with a very strange occurrence. I submitted the **same**
 code using PyPy and Python 2. The results are shown below:

[image: spoj large input test]

The code ran much faster using PyPy compared to CPython, as expected. But at the same time, the memory usage increased by a whopping 7 times! I did a search on the web but I was unable to find any evidence that suggests that PyPy's memory usage is much more than CPython. Could somone please explain the huge difference in memory usage?

I have also considered that it could be because of my code. Hence, I have posted my code below:

```
import io, sys, atexit, os
sys.stdout = io.BytesIO()
atexit.register(lambda: sys.__stdout__.write(sys.stdout.getvalue()))
sys.stdin = io.BytesIO(sys.stdin.read())
raw_input = lambda: sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()

line = list(map(int,raw_input().split()))
num, k = line
ans = 0

for i in xrange(0,num):
    if int(raw_input())%k == 0:
        ans += 1;

print(ans)
```

Could someone please advise me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I was not able to reproduce the results. Don't know which versions/set-ups are used by SPOJ. For the following experiments, PyPy 5.8.0 and CPython 2.7.12 were used.

As test case, the largest possible input file with size of about `110MB` was used:

```
#create_data.py
print 10**6, 33
for i in xrange(10**6):
  print 10**9

>> python create_data.py > input.in
```

Now running `/usr/bin/time -v XXX solution.py < input.py` yields:

```
Interpreter     MaximalResidentSize 
PyPy:                 278 Mb
CPython:              222 Mb
```

PyPy needs a little bit more memory. CPython and PyPy use different garbage collector strategies and I think PyPy's trade-off is to be faster but to use more memory. The guys from PyPy have a [great article](https://morepypy.blogspot.de/2013/10/incremental-garbage-collector-in-pypy.html) about their garbage collector and its comparison to CPython.

---

Second, I don't trust the numbers from the SPJO-site. `system.stdin.read()` will read the whole file into memory. The python documentation even [says](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string. size is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; **it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory**.

Under the assumption, that the worst case was include into their test cases, the memory usage should be at least the size of the file (110 MB) as you use `std.stdin.read()` and even twice the size, because you are coping the data.

---

Actually, I'm not sure, the whole trouble is worth it - using `raw_input()` is probably fast enough - I would just trust python to do The Right Thing. CPython normally buffers `stdout` and `stdin` (fully buffered if they are redirected to files, or line-buffered for the console) and you have to use command line option `-u` to [switch it off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering).

But if you really wanna be sure, you can use the file-object iterators of `sys.stdin`, because as CPython man pages state:

> -u     Force  stdin,  stdout  and  stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On
>          systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and  stderr  in
>          binary  mode.   Note  that **there is internal buffering** in xread‐
>          lines(), readlines() and **file-object  iterators  ("for  line  in
>          sys.stdin")**  which  is  not  influenced by this option.  To work
>          around this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()"  inside
>          a "while 1:" loop.

That means your program could look like this:

```
import sys
num, k = map(int,raw_input().split())
ans = 0    
for line in sys.stdin:
    if int(line)%k == 0:
        ans += 1
print(ans)
```

This has the big advantage that only around 7MB memory are used for this variant.

Another lessons is that you should not use `sys.stdin.readline()` if your are afraid, that somebody runs your program in the unbuffered mode.

---

some further experiments (with my cpu clocked down)

```
                   CPython        CPython -u         PyPy         PyPy -u
original        28sec/221MB      25sec/221MB       3sec/278MB    3sec/278MB
raw_input()     29sec/7MB        110sec/7MB        7sec/75MB    100sec/63MB
readline()     38sec/7MB        130sec/7MB        5sec/75MB    100sec/63MB
readlines()    20sec/560MB      20sec/560MB       4sec/1.4GB    4sec/1.4G
file-iterator    17sec/7MB       17sec/7MB         4sec/68MB    100sec/62MB
```

There are some takeaways:

1. `raw_input()` and `sys.stdin.read_line()` have identical performances
2. `raw_input()` is buffered, but this buffer seems to be a little bit different as the buffer for file-object iterator, which outperforms `raw_input()` at least for this file.
3. memory-overhead of `sys.stdin.readlines()` seems to be pretty hight, at least as long as the lines are short.
4. file-object iterator has different behavior in CPython and PyPy, if option `-u` is used: for PyPy `-u` switches off also the buffering for file-object iterator (maybe a bug?).

Comment: I just tested the code that you supplied. The results show that there is indeed buffering by reading sys.stdin when used in a for-in loop. If I understood you correctly, all i/o in python is buffered by default unless we switch off buffering?

Comment: @LanceHAOH I cannot speak for all OSes, but it is for Linux. There are however differences whether the input/output is redirected to file or not.

Comment: What a great answer. Kudos!